# Orbits in G = $Z_6$ by listing 2 element subsets in G.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, equivalence-relations, group-actions

1) Let $G = \mathbb{Z}_6$. List all 2-element subsets of $G$, and show that under the regular action of G (by left addition) there are 3 orbits, 2 of length 6, one of length 3. Deduce that the stabilizers of 2-element subsets of $G$ have order 1 or 2.

2) Carry out the same calculations as in the previous question for $S_3$,
showing that there are four orbits, of lengths 3, 3, 3 and 6.

These are the questions - I have the answers but what I am really struggling with is getting to grips with what it all means.

Firstly I know the definition of orbit to be the equivalence class for $x\sim y$ if $\theta(g)(x)=y$ for g$\in$G and $x,y\in X$ with $G$ being the Group and $X$ the set on which $G$ acts.

But what I am not seeing is how I can apply this to the questions. Is my "Set" the set of all two element subsets? And if so what is my group action $\theta$ and how can I apply it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two element subsets:

$$\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{0,3\},\{0,4\},\{0,5\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{1,5\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{2,5\},\{3,4\},\{3,5\},\{4,5\}.$$

Left addition: Take $\left[a\right]_6 \in \mathbb{Z}_6$ and do $a+H$ (where $H$ is a two element subset of $G$).

For example:

$$1+\{0,1\} =\{1,2\}, 1+\{1,2\} = \{2,3\}, 1+\{2,3\} = \{3,4\}, 1+\{3,4\} = \{4,5\}, 1+\{4,5\} = \{5,0\}, 1+\{5,0\} = \{0,1\} $$

Here is an example of an orbit of length $6$.

$\textbf{Lastly}$: To do a problem like this with maximum efficiency think of these sets as  ordered pairs $(x,y)$. If you want to show that there are three orbits, think of all the ordered pairs $(x,y)$ in which you can add $1,2,3,4,5$ to and get back to the original ordered pair.

Comment: Hi, by this do you mean changing the value of 'a' continuously until you return to H?

Comment: Yeah, $a \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. From this I suppose you can therefore show as there is no orbit of length < 3 that the stabalizers must be of order 1 or 2. And a similar method would be required for part 2.

Comment: Not sure if I follow 100%, dyou mind explaining what you mean in a little more detail? (In regards to the stabalizer).

Comment: $x \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. You are performing $x+H$ where $H$ is the subsets of 2 elements. If there were a cycle of length $<3$, namely $2$ is of interest to me. This will correspond to saying, $a+\{u_1,v_1\} = \{u_2,v_2\}, a+\{u_2,v_2\} = \{u_1,v_1\}$, but this is the same as $2a+\{u_1,v_1\} = \{u_1,v_1\}$. So now just figure out what $2a$ is in $\mathbb{Z}_6$.  You'll notice that is $a \in \mathbb{Z}_6$ then $2a =$ $2$ or $4$. Now just perform $2+H,4+H$.

Comment: I get it thanks a lot Rod.

Comment: Hi one last thing in regards to part 2. If I produce the orbits using the same method stated - I get the three orbits of length three to be: {id,(1 2)}, {(1 2 3),(1 3)}, {(1 3 2),(2 3)};
{id,(1 3)}, {(1 3 2),(1 2)}, {(1 2 3),(2 3)};
{id,(2 3)}, {(1 2 3),(1 2)}, {(1 3 2),(1 3)}: I can see now what the orbit of order 6 is: (I just simply take all the remaining doubles and there it is) but how to I actually generate this using your method of performing the group action continuously until you return to the initial value of H you started with.

Comment: Eg. If I take {id,(123)} [an element in the 6 cycle] and perform (12) on it I get: {id,(123)} -> {(12),(23)} -> {id,(123)} (Also just to check my understanding this is NOT an orbit as it doesn't contain every x : x $\in S_3$)

Comment: Remember now that the operation is composition or "multiplication".

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right. The set $X$ is the set of all two element subsets of $G$. For the action of $G$ on $X$, first note that $G$ has a regular action on itself. Use this action to define an action on $X$. More precisely, if $g_i \mapsto h_i$ and $g_j \mapsto h_j$ under the regular action of $G$ on itself $(i \neq j)$, then the action of $G$ on $X$ is defined as $\{g_i, g_j\} \mapsto \{h_i, h_j\}.$

Comment: Thanks Krish if I understand correctly you and Rod are hinting at more or less the same thing.

Comment: @mrhappysmile: Yeah. both are same, just stated differently. Rod's answer is more elaborate. I just gave a hint. But most important of all is that you understood.